# how to give auto scrolling to textview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating a game where depending on available hint count I want to show hints to player in textview. Now I want to give auto scrolling to textview, because whenever the new hint is added to previous hint, I need to scroll the textview to see the hint. that means whenever new hint is added I want to scroll to bottom of textview automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
[myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([myTextView.text length], 0)];
```